# Jquery replace string attribute shortcode

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I tried to replace an attribute value in a shortcode from a json string but I didn't succes with this code. Everything seems fine but it's not working...

string to replace (after stringify):

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data = '[vc_single_image image=\"3464\" border_color=\"grey\" img_link_large=\"\" img_link_target=\"_self\" img_size=\"large\"]'
data = data.replace(/\[vc_single_image(.*?)image="(.*?)"(.*?)]/g, '[vc_single_image$1image="placeholder-image-id"$3]');
```

it works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zg2e7/311/
But not after JSON.stringify

What's wrong?

Comment: `/\[vc_single_image(.*?)image="(.*?)"(.*?)\]/g`

Comment: Please show a typical string before replacing, and what it is supposed to look like after replacing. Also, please create a jsFiddle.

Comment: `not working`? please show expected matches and where it fails..

Comment: I edited my question. It fail, no error but didn't replace the string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to match:

```
\[vc_single_image(.*?)image=\\"(.*?)\\"(.*?)\]
                            ^^      ^^
```

Since your string is starting with `'`.. `\"` will be compiled as a part of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Effectively I have completely missed slashs after stringify array to json!